# How to enable TCP connection in Debian Squeeze?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, gnu

I need enable TCP connections to my system, for use graphical applications in marionnet, network simulation system, in debian squeeze.

In older versions of debian it is achieved with System|Administration|Login Window -> uncheck “Deny TCP connections to the Xserver”. but in squeeze I have no idea.

??

EDIT: I have the answer: take a look [here](http://laltromondo.dynalias.net/~iki/informatica/soft/listening_gdm3/)

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to execute GUI applications is over an [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) connection. Install an ssh server (`openssh-server` package) on your system. Run `ssh -X` or put `ForwardX11 yes` in `~/.ssh/config` on the client side.

Comment: And do you think that works for my specific case(marionnet)?

Comment: @D.D.C I'd never heard of marionnet until now, but I don't see why not. If you have trouble with it, feel free to ask questions here (but I recommend giving more information, since it's not a very common program).

Comment: Marionnet(marionnet.org) is a network simulation system, by each pc it runs a virtual machine(gnu/linux OS), then a command line prompt is shown exactly like a normal pc running gnu/linux, all command line programs works fine but if I wanna run a graphical app it fails with a message like this: Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 182.23.25.1'.